# Optional integration code for a framework: optional dependency or separate framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks, carthage

I’m the author of framework X, and I’d like to distribute little bits of glue code for **optionally** integrating with frameworks Y and Z. Clients should be able to use X as a standalone framework, but be able to use the integration code if they’re also using Y and/or Z.

The headline question is: **Is there a current best practice for doing this, and what are the tradeoffs?** Detailed subquestions follow below.

My specific case: I’m the author of [Siesta](https://github.com/bustoutsolutions/siesta). It takes only a little bit of code to integrate [with SwiftyJSON](https://gist.github.com/pcantrell/1825e30085d6ee03faaa) or [with Alamofire](https://github.com/bustoutsolutions/siesta/blob/cfb2bbc062e96277c996f9a48b37e9b15409f926/Source/Networking-Alamofire.swift). However, Siesta does not require either of those frameworks.

I see two acceptable options:

1. Configure frameworks Y and Z as **optional dependencies** of framework X in my Xcode build.
2. Distribute **separate frameworks**: X core, X+Y glue, and X+Z glue.

Option 1 seems promising at first glance. Isn’t this exactly what optional dependencies are for? But I worry because:

- I don’t see optional dependencies in widespread use.
- It’s not clear to me whether I will pin clients to specific versions of Y and Z by doing this.
- What about people using Carthage who build X from source? It looks like even if they don’t use Y or Z, they’ll have to include those frameworks in their `Cartfile.private` just to build X.

Option 2 is straightforward, but I’m concerned about overhead. Even a noop framework clocks in at > 250k. Is it still that bad in the final app? Is there a per-framework overhead that I should be concerned about if I go that route?

Are there other tradeoffs I’m not aware of?

Comment: FWIW, I gave up on making this work as the OQ states. I use submodules for the CocoaPods distro, and for the Carthage / framework distro, I make people manually include the files that use the optional frameworks.